# Send data present in context to a server action that makes an API call

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, server-action

So I have an e-commerce application built on Next.js.

I have userDetails saved in useContext API.

I want to send userDetails?.id to a server action that makes an API Call.

Is there way that I can achieve this ?

This below is the sever action defined in action.ts of my /shop page.

action.ts has 'use server' at line 1 of file.

```
export async function getAllListingData({
  currentCategoryUrlKey,
  userDetails,
  requestAttributes,
  isSortAscending,
  sortField,
}: GetCategoryProductsWithChildProductsPropTypes) {
  const requestBody = {
    categoryUrlKey: currentCategoryUrlKey,
    userDetails: userDetails,
    pageSize: 6,
    requestType: 'PLP',
    requestAttributes,
    isSortAscending,
    sortField,
  };

  const currentCategory = await getCategoryProductsArgoid(requestBody);

  const childCategoriesFilters = currentCategory?.childFilterCategories?.map(
    ({ name, urlKey }: ChildCategory) => ({ label: name, value: urlKey })
  );

  const categoriesWithProducts: CategoryWithProductsPropTypes[] = [];

  if (currentCategory?.childCategories?.length > 0) {
    for (const childCategory of currentCategory.childCategories) {
      const urlKey = generateUrlKey(childCategory.name);
      const req = {
        categoryUrlKey: urlKey,
        userDetails: userDetails,
        pageSize: 6,
        requestType: 'PLP',
        requestAttributes,
        isSortAscending,
        sortField,
      };
      const res = await getCategoryProductsArgoid(req);
      res.urlKey = urlKey;
      if (res?.products?.length > 0) {
        categoriesWithProducts.push(res);
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    currentCategory: currentCategory,
    metaData: currentCategory.metaData,
    childCategories: currentCategory?.childCategories,
    childCategoriesWithProducts: categoriesWithProducts,
    childCategoriesFilters,
  };
}
```

Issue is i can't use 'useUser' in the page since page is server rendered and useUser is a client side context.

```
'use client'
import {useUser} from 'userContext.ts';

export default function SomePage() {
const {userDetails} = useUser();
...
....

return(...)
}
```

How can I maintain SSR while sending this userDetails?.id in the server action's API call.

I tried converting page to client side caused issues of looping api calls.

Expectation:

Be able to send userDetails to getAllListingData() which is called in a server rendered page.